# Page_Load is not executed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this c# code

```
namespace ZumaApp
{

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ServiceReference1.QSLWebBookingSoapClient services;
        public String CallerId = "";
        public Int32 rowCount;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CallerId = Request["CallerID"];
```

and in my asp I have this:

```
<%@ Page Title="VMP Online Booking" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ZumaApp._Default" %>
```

#### My problem

The page load function is not executing.

#### how did I know that

First: I make a break point on the first line in the Page_Load function, but visual studio doesn't stop at the break point.

second: I make a break point at this line `public String CallerId = "";` and Visual studio stops on that line, then I press `step over` but the page loaded without going to the Page_Load function.

I tried clean and rebuild but dones't help

Comment: Are u sure that you have attached the event handler Page_Load to the Load event of the page ?

Comment: Try Overriding Page_Load for "OnLoad" and called the based to see what you've got!

Comment: @DTs Actually I got this code from a friend. How can I know if the event handler Page_Load had been attached to the page?

Comment: @JudgeProphet do you mean change the Page_Load to OnLoad?

Comment: @user3432257 Yeah but you have to use "override" something like "public override void onLoad(....)"

Comment: Try delete the `.Designer` and recreate it by `Convert to web application` option.

Comment: @Bharadwaj do you mean delete this class `Default.aspx.designer.cs` ?

Comment: @user3432257 Yes. It can be regenerated by right clicking on the aspx / ascx file and select `Convert to web application` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try delete the `.Designer.cs` and recreate it by Convert to web application option.

It can be regenerated by right clicking on the `aspx / ascx` file and select Convert to web application option.

Some times `.Designer.cs` wont be refreshed by VS, and need to apply this method to get a fresh `.Designer.cs` file.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
<%@ Page Title="VMP Online Booking" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="_Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ZumaApp._Default" %>
```

Comment: That sneaky AutoEventWireup strikes again!  (Always when you least expect it.)  :(

Answer (score 0):

In the `InitializeComponent` function (which resides in the "Web Form Designer
generated code" region), you should have a line which says:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
```

This line of code should be automatically generated, and tells the framework
to execute the Page_Load function when the page loads. If this line is
missing, the Page_Load function won't fire. Adding this line should solve
your problem.

Reference: [Page_Load Not Firing?](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/297774-page_load-not-firing)

Comment: I don't have the function `InitializeComponent ` in my `Default.aspx.designer.cs` class